# Where do you go to find inspiration for website designs?

Tags: css, color-scheme

Starting from scratch is hard. How do you do it? I quite like color lovers for some palette ideas but after that I just browse randomly until I find soemthing that catches my eye.

Comment: You've already arrived at the answer I would have given.

Comment: What John says, and coolhomepages.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**http://www.csszengarden.com**](http://www.csszengarden.com/) - epic CSS designs.

[**http://www.colorschemedesigner.com**](http://www.colorschemedesigner.com/) - the only color scheme generator application you will ever need.

Having said that, I always try to remember I *am not* a designer but rather a programmer. As such, I do **my** job the best I can, and hand over the designing to people who's job is to handle just that.

Answer (score 1):

Kiril's website: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/

Blogs titled "Drinking From The Firehose – Design Inspiration"
are really a point to draw lot of Design inspiration. Here is the search results:
http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?s=drinking+from

Answer (score 1):

Besides just bookmarking of sites through normal browsing activities I'll look at competitive sites that are in same segment.

**If I have a bit of a budget** I tend to browse through sites like [templatemonster](http://www.templatemonster.com/) or put an auction on [99 designs](http://99designs.com/).  Actually these are good without a budget just for pure window shopping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option for color pallets - look around you.  See something you like?  Take a picture of it, then use a color picker software that allows you to click an image to capture the color at the click point.  Capture all the colors in the picture for your scheme that way.

Nature has a LOT of nice color schemes!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webcreme.com/

http://spyrestudios.com/

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/